# GRPC: Passing JSON with proto.Message field between browser and server

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-web

I've been struggling with passing a JSON with Message values back and forth between systems. Got a bit further, but I'm still not there. A Struct seems to be the way but even though the struct I'm sending looks perfectly fine, it is empty once received by the server.

`Result` is passed from a web browser (grpc-web) to a Python backend. The Python backend should serialize `Result` to JSON (to store it) and back again.

```
// proto
message Result {
    google.protobuf.Struct variables = 1;
}

// obj - Where variables would contain a (1 level deep) JSON with different types of values, e.g.:
{
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": true,
    "key3": proto_msg_a //instance of proto.MessageA
}

// code
struct = new proto.google.protobuf.Struct(obj);
req = new Request;
req.variables = struct;
```

Checking `req.variables` before sending shows that it's indeed a `Struct` with all the correct fields in it. But once the other end (server) receives it `req.variables` is an empty `Struct`. For testing purposes I tried an `obj` that is simply `{'key': 'value'}`, but the result was the same.

So then I tried `proto.google.protobuf.Struct.fromJavaScript`:

```
// code
struct = proto.google.protobuf.Struct.fromJavaScript(vars);
req = new Request;
req.variables = struct;
```

This works for a simple `obj` (e.g. `{"key": "val"}`), but for an `obj` with a proto message field (such as above) it resulted in :

```
struct_pb.js:875 Uncaught Error: Unexpected struct type.
    at Function.proto.google.protobuf.Value.fromJavaScript (struct_pb.js:875)
    at Function.proto.google.protobuf.Struct.fromJavaScript (struct_pb.js:941)
    at Function.proto.google.protobuf.Value.fromJavaScript (struct_pb.js:871)
    at Function.proto.google.protobuf.Struct.fromJavaScript (struct_pb.js:941)
    at Function.proto.google.protobuf.Value.fromJavaScript (struct_pb.js:871)
    at Function.proto.google.protobuf.Struct.fromJavaScript (struct_pb.js:941)
    at Function.proto.google.protobuf.Value.fromJavaScript (struct_pb.js:871)
    at Function.proto.google.protobuf.Struct.fromJavaScript (struct_pb.js:941)
```

Or can I, instead of going through all the troubles with protobuf/json in javascript, just use a `map`?

```
// proto
message Request {
    map<string, ?type?> variables = 1;
}
```

But what  would `?type?` then be if it the values can ben anything (proto.MessageX, string, boolean, etc)?

I would really like to use proto messages in variables. The reason for picking protobuf/grpc was exactly this, being able to use the same type throughout our complete platform, but this seems to be blocking this goal. Did I miss something? What would you do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not answering **your** question exactly, but I was having an issue with `Struct.fromJavaScript` that might be somewhat related.

**TL;DR**

You can't have `undefined` (or any invalid JSON) in whatever you pass to `Struct.fromJavaScript`. This includes any deeply nested fields if you're passing an object.

The way I'm fixing this for my solution is to `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` the object I want to turn into a Struct before passing it to `Struct.fromJavaScript` to remove all fields with invalid JSON:

```js
const obj = { ... }

const stringifiedJSON = JSON.stringify(obj)
const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(stringifiedJSON)

const newStruct = Struct.fromJavaScript(parsedJSON)
```

---

I was looking around for what causes this error for a while, and it looks like in the struct implementation of `google-protobuf`, there's a switch statement that looks something like this:

```js
proto.google.protobuf.Value.fromJavaScript = function(value) {
  var ret = new proto.google.protobuf.Value();
  switch (goog.typeOf(value)) {
    case 'string':
      ret.setStringValue(/** @type {string} */ (value));
      break;
    case 'number':
      ret.setNumberValue(/** @type {number} */ (value));
      break;
    case 'boolean':
      ret.setBoolValue(/** @type {boolean} */ (value));
      break;
    case 'null':
      ret.setNullValue(proto.google.protobuf.NullValue.NULL_VALUE);
      break;
    case 'array':
      ret.setListValue(proto.google.protobuf.ListValue.fromJavaScript(
          /** @type{!Array} */ (value)));
      break;
    case 'object':
      ret.setStructValue(proto.google.protobuf.Struct.fromJavaScript(
          /** @type{!Object} */ (value)));
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error('Unexpected struct type.');
  }
  return ret;
};
```

It looks like it just goes through the object fields and checks the types of the fields, then it will throw the `Unexpected struct type` error if the type is not one of the previous cases. This means that if the field is `undefined`, the error will throw.

Also, the type definition on `Struct.fromJavaScript` is this:

```
(method) Struct.fromJavaScript(value: {
    [key: string]: JavaScriptValue;
}): Struct
```

where `JavaScriptValue` is

```
export type JavaScriptValue = null | number | string | boolean | Array<any> | {};
```

And if you pass an object with `undefined` into `fromJavaScript` directly instead of through a typed variable...

```
Struct.fromJavaScript({
  field: undefined, // this will cause a compile-time error
})

// ----------

type WeirdObj = {
  field?: string
}

const obj: WeirdObj = {
  field: undefined,
}

Struct.fromJavaScript(obj) // this will throw a run-time error

// ----------

type WeirdUndefinedObj = {
  field: string | undefined
}

const undefinedObj: WeirdUndefinedObj = {
  field: undefined,
}

Struct.fromJavaScript(undefinedObj) // this will cause a compile-time error
```

This confused me for a while, because `fromJavaScript` (to me) seems like I can pass it JavaScript, and I'll get a struct back in return. Maybe the method should be `fromJSON` instead, and update the types to prevent `undefined` from getting passed into the method in the first place.